# Laravel: redirecTo() method is not working correctly

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-request, laravel-authentication

I have been trying to redirect a user after login, users are to be redirected to when a certain condition is fulfilled.

**In the LoginController provided by Laravel**

```
line 31->protected function redirectTo(Request $request){
            if($request->session()->has('credentials')){

            $branch_id = $request->session()->get('credentials')[1];

            return view('/home'.$branch_id);
        }
        else{
            return view('/auth.login');
        }
    }
```

**In the RedirectifAuthenticated.php by laravel.**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            $setBranch = User::on('default')->where('email', $request->email)->first();
            $request->session()->put(['branch_id' => $setBranch->branch_id]);
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

In my AssetController.php file

```
 public function count_assets(Request $request, $branch = null) {

    //set branch id in session for super admin by getting branch in the url that was selected
    $setBranch = Branch::on('default')->where('branch_db', $branch)->first();
    if($setBranch != null){
        session(['branch_id' => $setBranch->branch_id]);
    }

    $count_assets = Asset::get()->count();
    $count_items = Item::get()->count();
    $count_department = Department::get()->count();
    $count_support = User_support::get()->count();
    $count_items_trans = Item_assignment::get()->count();
    $count_assignment = Assignment::get()->count();
    $count_staff = Staff::get()->count();

    return view('home', [ 'count_assets' => $count_assets,'count_items' => $count_items, 'count_department' => $count_department, 'count_support' => $count_support,
        'count_items_trans' => $count_items_trans, 'count_assignment' => $count_assignment, 'count_staff' => $count_staff]);
}
```

Now in the web.php file i've got route like this

```
Route::get('/home/{branch?}', 'AssetController@count_assets');
```

When i try logging in, it says

```
ErrorException Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::redirectTo() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mis_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers.php on line 15 and defined

LoginController.php (line 31)
```

Comment: Where are you calling the redirectTo function?The error says you forgot to pass in a Request Object into it and that it happens on `RedirectsUsers.php at line 15` , I don't see that file in your post.  But check there and make sure you are passing in a Request object into the function when using it, as right now it is complaining you are not.

Comment: The redirectTo function is been called in the RedirectsUsers.php                   `public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
            return $this->redirectTo();
        }
        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
    }` @AaronLamar

Comment: ok, so it doesn't look like this line `return $this->redirectTo();` is passing in the required arguments for that function. Is that what is on line 15? The error is saying you need to pass in a `Request` object.  Look at Laravel's [Request](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html) object to see how to use it or maybe there is one available inside RedirectUsers.php.  Sorry,  I am no expert in laravel but that is at least what the error seems to tell us.

Comment: Like you said, i needed to return a $request from where the redirectTo function was being called. Thanks a lot @AaronLamar